# How to Set that my element dont get Tabfocus?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control [Transition Control in mvvm](http://www.japf.fr/2009/04/adding-transitions-to-a-mvvm-based-dialog/comment-page-1/#comment-3515).I want that  in this sample the content control can not got keyboardfocus...how do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820628) to enable tab stop.

Answer (score 1):

You need `IsTabStop` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<ContentControl IsTabStop="False".. />` rather than `KeyBoardNavigation.IsTabStop`